# How to change sorting option in a rdlc report programmatically?

Tags: c#, sorting, report, rdlc

I have a report with 1 group, sorted by date. This is how it looks:

[Link to image](http://puu.sh/aI7yH/ec4544a154.png) (Fecha is date)

Id like to have in my form 2 radio buttons which will tell the report how to sort the rows. How can i change the sorting to a different field programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ReportParameter` to sorting programmatically a report.

You have only two `RadioButton` so you can set an expression like this as `SortBy`:

```
=IIf(Parameters!SortByField1.Value, Fields!Field1.Value, Fields!Field2.Value)
```

`SortByField1` is a `Boolean` parameter and you can set it with this code:

```
ReportParameter SortByField1 = new ReportParameter("SortByField1", YourRadioButtonToSortByField1.Checked);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved it! First i struggled with the fact i couldn't send a true or false as a ReportParameter but sending the string "true" or "false" worked. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry! I am a vb.net programmer and in this language you can pass a Boolean to ReportParameter. The page I visited to copy a C# declaration suggest using .ToString but I delete this part: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms252146%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: hahaha it's okay! i ended up with a `radiobtn.checked ? "true" : "false"` haha and that worked :D i didn't even know "IIF" existed haha so thanks again :D